# Is git not able to tell which commits were only made to that branch?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

So if two developers create their own branches (A and B) from the dev branch, make their commits, then A and B are merged in (consecutively) to dev, then B is checked-out again, fast-forwarded, and new commits made, and management says they now need B to go live (to master) but not A, a merge from branch B to master will also include commits from branch A, so is a rebase (even interactively) to master from B the only way to get only changes from B, or is there some easier way using the `merge` command or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the *changes* introduced by branch `A`, simply `git revert` the merge commit where `A` got merged. This will create a new commit that undoes the changes from `A`.

If there must be no history of `A` in the release, you have to rebase the `B` commits made after the merge of `A` onto the commit just before the merge of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question:

> Is git not able to tell which commits were only made to that branch

**...is NO!**

Now, you may be able to reverse-engineer things manually by inspecting your tree, but that will never be fool-proof (can never be truly automated). For example, if a fast-forward merge occurred (leaving no merge-commit) there is no information that Git tracks to say that it at one point was reachable by a certain branch.

**This is the reason why:**

What is a branch in Git? It is simply a pointer that points to a commit. That commit (which is the "tip" of that branch) has descendants which make up the rest of what is "reachable" by that branch. When a new commit is made and your HEAD points to one of these branches, that branch pointer will now point to that new commit.

So actually, in Git, "branch" is not even that great of a term when compared to other historical VCS tools. Perhaps "moving pointer" would be more descriptive.

**In your situation, you will need to manually inspect which commits should and should-not be promoted to master and perform the cleanup using tools such as interactive rebasing.**

Comment: Thanks, I use git rebase -i now if I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will definitely need to rewrite history to prevent the commits from `A` that are now included in `B` from getting included in master.

The last few commits that were added to `B` after it was merged with `A` build on top of commits that came (amongst other places) from `A`, so you cannot simply leave them out. This would change the last couple commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use rebase --onto. See docs   [git rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/de/v1/Git-Branching-Rebasing) Or use cherry-pick.